# Why do polar solvents seem to be of lesser viscosity than non-polar ones?

Tags: solvents, liquids

For instance, in Russian there is an adjective "oily", which means a liquid of high viscosity. Is this assertion even true in general or statistically?

Comment: Water and benzene, as an example of polar and non-polar solvent, do not differ much in their visosities reported [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Other_common_substances).

Comment: Non-polar pentane is much less viscous than water. So the assertion is clearly not true in general. It might still be true as a very vague and imprecise rule of thumb, much like _"all liquids have density 1"_.

Comment: Having long chain or ring molecules that get tangled up easily sounds like a good way to increase viscosity, compared with a small molecules like water. If we compare liquids whose molecules are more or less similar in size and shape we probably find that polar ones are more viscous.

Comment: @OscarLanzi but is there a single highly-viscous polar solvent?

Comment: When I first read this I thought you had gotten things the wrong way around. I usually associate higher viscosity with H-bonding liquids like water. Consider just pentane and hexane in eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_viscosities. Non-volatile oils are not volatile because of their high b.p. which is due to their high MW, as a result of which they are also viscous.

Comment: The key is to compare comparable molecules. Consider n-pentane as non-polar solvent,and replace the terminal CH2 by O to get polar n-butanol. A huge increase of viscosity.

Comment: I think I got what you mean. But has to do more with "wetting power" and adhesion rather than viscosity. And you can find always a solvent that is more oily looking but polar and the opposite, and all aspects mixed.

Answer (score 2):

Viscosity depends on the intermolecular forces between molecules. Typically, the more viscous a substance or liquid is, the stronger its intermolecular forces are. In polar solvents, there are dipole-dipole interactions while in non-polar solvents, there are London Dispersion Forces. Sometimes, when individual molecules are large, LDF can be stronger than dipole-dipole interactions in some polar solvents. The point is that having stronger intermolecular forces will lead to higher viscosity, and being polar doesn't mean it will have stronger IMF than non-polar substances.